# Quotient Spaces of Infinite Dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ and let
$W$ be a subspace of polynomials divisible by $x^4$,
find the dimension of $V/W$. I can solve if $V$ is finite dimensional but don't know what to do if $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: I think $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is a basis for $V/W$.

Comment: How this can be basis for the quotient space.

Comment: ofcourse I mean the residue classes of these elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the map $T\colon V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ by
$$T\left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\right) = (a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3),$$
meaning that you keep only the first four coefficients of any polynomial.
This is a surjective linear map, and its kernel is
$$\text{ker}(T) = \left\{\sum_{i=4}^n a_ix^i\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}, a_i\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$
Note that $\text{ker}(T) = W$. The induced map
$$\tilde{T}\colon V/W\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$$
is thus an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $V$ is a $k$-algebra, and $W$ is an ideal of this algebra. As a quotient algebra $V/W$ is $k[x]/(x^4)$, isomorphic as a vector space to $\{f(x)\in k[x]\mid \deg f(x)\le 3\}$.

Thus a basis for $V/W$ is $(1+W, x+W, x^2+W, x^3+W)$.